# Custom action to open an program instance for each selected folder?

Tags: thunar

In Thunar, I want to be able to open folders with [Ex Falso](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_Falso_%28software%29).

I created a custom action with the command `/usr/bin/exfalso %f`. This works when I select a single folder. When I select several folders, I want Thunar to open an Ex Falso instance for each selected folder.

I tried the parameters `%F` and `%N`, but then Ex Falso gets opened for the first folder only.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering if rather than attempt to do it this way, rather you created a shell script that took the `%f` argument as the custom command and then did something like this internally:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$@"; do
  echo "/usr/bin/exfalso $i"
done
```

This will generate a series of commands like this:

```
$ ./myexfalso_lancher.bash 1 2 3 "4 5"
/usr/bin/exfalso 1
/usr/bin/exfalso 2
/usr/bin/exfalso 3
/usr/bin/exfalso 4 5
```

Which is what you want. To make this live you'll just need to change the `echo` line to this:

```
/usr/bin/exfalso "$i"
```

Problems with this approach that you may or may not care about.

1. If the files/folders you're dealing with contain spaces, then the `for` loop might not work if the arguments from `%f` are not quoted. Switching that to a `while` loop with a `read` statement might be able to better deal with spaces in names of files or folders.
2. I'm not 100% sure what the command argument should be that you pass into the script. I'm guessing it's `%f` but you might need to use something else.
3. You might want to put some guards into this script that limit how many exfalso's it can launch. A simple counter going through the loop could do this. Once it gets to say 10, it could exit.

Comment: works well (when you don't have any spaces in your paths)

Comment: @Lucas - I fixed a typo in the script that should deal with the space issue, can you try it again?

Comment: hehe I came back to fix that too since I found help in #bash. Thanks for editing, works flawless ;)

Comment: @Lucas - Glad the issue got resolved, finally. Please mark this A as accepted if you don't mind, so other's know your issue's been resolved.